# Exporting html table with dropdowns, to excel using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I have a html table with a few cells containing dropdowns which I am trying to export to Excel using table2excel jquery plugin. The plugin exports all the cells except for the ones containing the select tag. How do I get around this problem?

Sample html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="javascript">
        var tableToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)     
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
        })()    
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">

<table id="testTable" summary="Sample tabe to export to excel" rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2">
    <thead valign="top">
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a table HTML dynamically, so you can format the cell as per your need

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,",
    template =
      '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      });
    };
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table);
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || "Worksheet", table: generateTable(table) };
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  };
})();
function generateTable(table) {
  let innerHTML = `
        <thead  valign="top">
          <tr>
            ${Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("thead th ")).map(function(
              columnHeader
            ) {
              return `<th>${columnHeader.innerText}</th>`;
            }).join('')}
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          ${Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr ")).map(
            function(row) {
              return `<tr>
                        ${Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("td")).map(
                          function(cell) {
                            let text = "";
                            Array.from(cell.childNodes).forEach(childNode => {
                              switch (childNode.nodeType) {
                                case 1: {
                                  if (
                                    childNode.nodeName === "SELECT" ||
                                    childNode.nodeName === "INPUT"
                                  ) {
                                    text = text + childNode.value;
                                  }
                                  break;
                                }
                                case 3: {
                                  text = text + childNode.textContent;

                                  break;
                                }
                              }
                            });

                            return `<td>${text}</td>`;
                          }
                        ).join("")}</tr>`;
            }
          ).join("")}
        </tbody>
      `;
  console.log(innerHTML);
  return innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">

  <table id="testTable" summary="Sample tabe to export to excel" rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2">
    <thead valign="top">
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```